# Insets hides behind a surface

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, text, inset

MacOS, Version 12.1

In the following code, the "Hi" is above the surface, but you still can't see it from above.

```
g = Graphics3D[{}, ViewPoint -> 10^3 {1, 1, 1}];
g = Show[g,
  Plot3D[0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}],
  Graphics3D[Inset[Text[Style["Hi", FontSize -> 200]], {0, 0, 1}]]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Your `RegionFunction -> vis` isn't specified for us.

Comment: @uC-Harry  Edited my post to remove this issue.

Answer (score 2):

If your RegionFunction ist specified as:

```
RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, True],
```

you will see:

[image]

Your edited code is giving me the following output picture by running Mathematica 12.0 without any special settings:

[image]

If I'm turning the plane given by the Plot3D null function around the "Hi" is always fully visible.

Comment: Nice answer.  I see you snuck in a German "ist" in your answer ;p

Comment: I have version 12.1

Comment: Present code renders the same for me in version 11